# Router changes the url but not the components rendered

Tags: reactjs

Okay so when someone logs in, it should redirect him to the phones component. But from some reason it only changes the URL to /phones and doesnt render the component. I think it may be smth to do with the api I am using https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/warp/etn-device-checker-test/1.0#/default/post_login where token might be required but not sure. Thanks for any advices.

Login.js

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    
   
    let history = useHistory()
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const getIn = {
      
        "login":email,
        "password":password,
        
    
      };
  
      
      axios
        .post('https://js-test-api.etnetera.cz/api/v1/login', getIn,
        {
            headers: {
                
                 'content-type': 'application/json', 
           }
        }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data); 
      history.push("/phones");
    })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
       
    };
    return (
        <div>
           <form >
         <label>email</label> <input value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="text"/>
        <label>password</label>  <input type="text" value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={onSubmit}>login</button>
           </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

app.js

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './Login';
import MobileList from './mobileList';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
 <Router>
 <Switch>
 <Route>
<Login path='/login' exact/>
</Route>

 <Route>
 <MobileList path='/phones' exact/>
 </Route>
 
 </Switch>
 



 

 </Router>
 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

mobileList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { MobileContext } from './MobileContext';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Mobile from './Mobile';
function MobileList() {
    const { mobiles } = useContext(MobileContext);
    return (
        <div>
         {mobiles.map((item) => (
          <Mobile
           vendor={item.vendor}
          />
        ))}  
        hezasdccccccccccccccc 
        </div>
    )
}

export default MobileList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `path` prop on the `Route`, not on its children:

```
<Route path='/login' exact>
    <Login /> 
</Route>
<Route path='/phones' exact>
    <MobileList />
</Route>
```